# Batch modify file name and add ascending numbers

Tags: python, sorting, batch-file, terminal, rename

I have a bunch of TIFF image files ordered by date. I need to rename them using either python, or terminal commands. The file names are structured like this:

- basename_unnecessary_x.tif

where:

- basename = is part of the original filename I need to keep (16 characters long)
- unnecessary = part of the original filename I want to discard (14 characters long)
- x = ascending numbers I need to add. Starting at 0 and going up in steps of 250 for every subsequent file.

I know there are plenty of questions on batch renaming and adding ascending numbers to file names but I haven't found anything that keeps part of the original filename and deletes another portion *and* adds ascending numbers. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried in on your own?? please share your code! remember that SO is not a free code writing service... and please explain what you mean by "I have [...] files ordered by date"; do you have a sorted list of files in a text file? or do you view them sorted by date in Windows Explorer?? or is it part of the task of the script to sort the files properly?

Comment: Hi aschipfl. The codes I've been using either rename the files by removing the original filename and just adding numbers, and I've come across these on threads on this website. I have tried it by myself but I am by no means a proficient code write so I apologise but I do not have a code of my own.

Comment: And to answer your questions, by date I mean that the files are ordered by the date they were created when I view them in the finder on a mac. I don't have a text file with a list of the filenames but I have just made one now. I don't need the script to sort the files properly, but I can see that would be very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first get all file names you wanted to rename into a text file.

if you want to rename all files in the directory then simply run below command and redirect it to a text file.[ changed code, it will now list .tif files only]

```
dir /a:-D /b *.tif >cp1.txt
```

Now use below code , which will rename files ***basename_unnecessary_x.tif*** to ***basename_0.tif*** and so on.

```
@echo off
CD %CD%\<Folderpath in which .tif files should be renamed>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0
echo --------Script started -------------------------
echo.
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (cp1.txt) do (
echo original file name %%a
echo ------------------------------------------
for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%b in ("%%a") do ( 

echo file will be renamed to %%b_!count!.tif
echo ------------------------------------------
rename %%a %%b_!count!.tif
set /a count+=250
)
)
echo.
echo --------Script Completed -------------------------
```

Changes to the script :

1. dir command will now only list .tif files to cp1.txt
2. you can execute the script from any location , provided you update the path    in CD section of code.
3. Updated the code now, it will follow the sequence of 0 to 250 .. so on.

FYI the reason it was giving 250 to the first files even though i have initialized to zero , because i have increased it by 250 before using it in rename command.

Comment: Hi prudviraj, thank you very much for your reply.
I think I probably wasn't clear in my question. I should've written mac terminal. Either way that is not a problem as I can use the command prompt in a windows virtual machine.
creating the text file with the list of files with your first code works fine.
However  with the renaming code I keep getting:
%%a was unexpected at this time
I usually copy and paste code into the command line. Am I doing that right?
Thanks again.

Comment: when you are running from command line you need to use %a instead of %%a , my advise to you is copy the whole code into a text file and save it with a.bat extension and try running it. please let me know if you need help

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your reply. I have progressed quite a bit.
I had to put the a.bat file in a sub directory and use the call command to call a.bat from that folder. Otherwise the code attempted to also rename the batch file.
So the only files and folders in the directory are the tif files, the folder where the batch file is and the text file with the list of tif files. The renaming code works, however the it begins at 250, rather than 0? Your code clearly initialises with 0 then +=250 so I don't understand. 
For some reason I didnt get any %%a errors so I didn't change them.

Comment: @AGB , please use the updated code and let me know in case you have issues with it. Please vote up and accept my answer if you found it helpful. Thanks

Comment: Hi Prudviraj, it worked! That was very helpful indeed. Thank you very much. I am not able to upvote you as I do not have enough reputation to do it, but I did accept your answer.

Comment: @prudviraj I have files in a folder with an ext of `.cfx` and `.cfx_2` I how do I create a `for /r` loop to rename all of the files in my batch file I have a script but it only renames 1 of the 4 files..